# How can I see if the current page is loaded in a ThickBox?

Tags: jquery, lightbox, thickbox

I'm using ThickBox for a lightbox and I need to check if the current page exists within a TB or not. How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: on an unrelated side note, read this from the thickbox site. Paul Irish (you know who) writes "While Thickbox had its day, it is not maintained any longer, so we recommend you use some alternatives." http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/ why still use that

Comment: Legacy code that we're locked into on a LARGE project =(

Comment: oh sorry. and all the best :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably your boxed page could check for a container. On the demo site, the container  has the id `TB_window`. So in that example, you could do something like this:

```
if( $('selector-for-stuff-that-might-be-boxed').closest('#TB_window').size() ){
  // you're probably in a box
}
```

Note: if the point of this is to apply different styles to the boxed content, you can do that with just regular CSS by adding that ID to the CSS selector:

```
/* applies to non-boxed content */
.my-style { /*...*/ }


/* applies to boxed content */
#TB_window .my-style { /*...*/ }
```